# You only got a few seconds, to realize what just happened

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

### Riddle originally from [Junior Graphic : Issue 543](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=BqSG61Mv3UUC&pg=PP7&lpg=PP7&dq=I%20am%20a%20tale%20in%20children%E2%80%99s%20minds.%20I%20keep%20their%20secrets%20and%20share%20them%20inside.&source=bl&ots=4inJkMqneq&sig=2iDkRfykqdGdpLIWsGGSf58x_7o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXgdCs_PDYAhXEOI8KHa_DBdgQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=I%20am%20a%20tale%20in%20children%E2%80%99s%20minds.%20I%20keep%20their%20secrets%20and%20share%20them%20inside.&f=false)

I am a tale in children’s minds.
I keep their secrets and share them inside.
I blur their thoughts into fantasies kept
Like a canvas of art or a submarine depth.
Though an illusion, it occurs every night;
I give them a fantasy, I give them a fright.
Neither good or bad, but always nigh’
It’s interesting to tell.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are a

> Dream

Explanation:

I am a tale in children’s minds, I keep their secrets and share them inside.

> Dreams are in children's mind and they usually keep secrets in dreams.

I blur their thoughts into fantasies kept
Like a canvas of art or a submarine depth

> Dreams bring about new fantasies and paint new hobbies on blank canvas i.e. children's mind

Though an illusion, it occurs every night;
I give them a fantasy, I give them a fright.

> Dreams are just illusions. Nightmares as well.

Neither good nor bad, but always nigh’
It’s interesting to tell.

> Dreams are always interesting to share.

Comment: I thought of the same answer, but I would think some of them can be bad...

Comment: So what's "You only got a few seconds, to realize what just happened" supposed to mean?

Comment: @Acccumulation Ceasing to experience this and so losing recollection after a few seconds. There's a relevant xkcd, but spoilers.